# Opening a read only URL with password

Tags: custom-wordpress-pages

New to Web site dev, though have done a lot of coding of other sorts in the past, just set up a personal blog for my own amusement on bluehost using wordpress and have it installed locally for dev.
I have a training log on another site which anyone can open read-only to view training stats with a URL of the form below, this works fine in a browser:

https://www.othersite.com/logs/1234xyz/authenticate?password=thisismypassword

What I have tried to do unsuccessfully is have this open in a frame on one of my web pages (used iframe/object in html). It seems impossible to do this as the authentication string is not passed across, and the screen displayed prompts for manual input of the password. Can I open this automatically in some way?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, your solution is insecure regardless it works or not. In this way your clients can see the password of your (or another) site.
I suggest to query the external content using custom php code and display (print) it on your page.
There are several ways to get content of an external page:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php
If you need a tutorial for WP plugins check this out:
https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-wordpress-plugin/

Comment: Much appreciate the reply. I wasn't too bothered by security aspect, the password supplied gives a read access to some unimportant data and is available for public view. Though I appreciate the point. I have had a good look at php manual and see how his works but am still struggling with the authentication issue.

Comment: The other site holding the data is not owned by me. The account on it is mine. So i have set the read password and as I said it works using url in browser. However using code below I simply get the prompt for password displayed, can I get the page open with the data using this sort of method to send on the password.

Comment: <?php
$opts = array(
  'https'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Authorization: Basic mypassword" )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

/* Sends an http request to www.example.com
   with additional headers shown above */
$fp = fopen('https://www.runningahead.com/logs/26783806560744eea9d746b8455f70f6/', 'r', false, $context);
fpassthru($fp);
fclose($fp);
?>

Comment: The mypassword is the 64bit encoding of the password.